# angular 4 add grid controls to formGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am having a grid where one of the columns is the input box. I want all of these input boxes be a part of the same form group. How can I achieve that?

My is something like:

```
    <form [formGroup]="pricesFormGroup">

        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
                    <td>
                        {{product.productName}}
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <!--This is control I need to add to my formgroup-->
                        <input type="text"
                                [(ngModel)]="product.Price"
                                required>                                   
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? FormArray?

Comment: How did it go with my answer? Was the solution suitable for you? :)

Comment: @AJT_82, I've got more specs that invalidated an approach of having the form like that but I think this would work for what I was trying to achieve in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd want to have just that one value, I would do some preparation and make the formgroup as such, that you can directly display it in template and ignore `products` array completely. Here in this sample I set `product.name` as the property name, and `product.Price` as the value:

```ts
iterable = []; // store formgroup object keys to be displayed in template
pricesFormGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.pricesFormGroup = this.fb.group({});
  this.populateForm();
 }

populateForm() {
  this.products.forEach(x => {
    this.pricesFormGroup.addControl(x.productName, new FormControl(x.Price))
  })
  this.iterable = Object.keys(this.pricesFormGroup.value)
}
```

and template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="pricesFormGroup">
  <div *ngFor="let pro of iterable">
    <p>{{pro}}</p>
    <input [formControlName]="pro">
  </div>
</form>
```

This would produce..

```ts
{
  myProductName1: myProduct1_price
  // ...
}
```

Please ignore my poor naming conventions :D

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csaxlp?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Good choice for naming item of iterable :)

Comment: Ha, I have my moments :P :P Thanks for the uppie @yurzui ;)